# What's the saying for when you have the exact change to pay for something?

Tags: phrase-request, spoken-language

I just went to collect an item I bought over Ebay and wanted to tell the seller that I had the exact amount of cash with me and he didn't need to worry about handing over change. How do I say this? I'm sure I heard a phrase once, but it's escaped me now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could say:

> Ich habe den Betrag/das Geld **passend** dabei.

or short:

> Ich hab's **passend**.

*Passend* means the amount of cash you have fits exactly what you want to pay.

Comment: Note that while the first option is more of a full sentence and might be better in situations prone to misunderstandings, it would definitely sound a bit off in everyday situations (like at a supermarket till, or an ebay deal), where you'd definitely want to use the second version.

Answer (score 6):

The phrase is *passend* as, for example, in

> - Ich zahle *passend*.
> - Ich habe es *passend*.

Answer (score 6):

Where I live, you would say

> Ich hab's genau

or

> Ich kann es Ihnen genau geben

In context when you are shopping in a store, often prefaced by "Warten Sie" (to stop the cashier from searching out the change to give you - actually, this would have applied to your situation as well)

"Genau" is of course the German word for "exact(ly)"

Answer (score 5):

A somewhat more formal term is *abgezählt*:

> Bitte halten Sie das Geld abgezählt bereit.

meaning that one is supposed to hold the exact amount ready in order to be able to pay quickly (e.g. when many people are waiting in a line).

However, saying "Ich habe das Geld abgezählt" is somewhat unsual (although not incorrect).

Comment: As you say, "das Geld abgezählt bereithalten" is done prior to approaching the point of sale, to speed up the process of payment. It is thus a prerequisite for "passend zahlen"...

Answer (score 0):

Another helpful phrase for when you would like to round up and hand over that amount:

"Stimmt so".

Comment: While true, that doesn't answer the question.